# how to exactly get an explicit form of a trig differential problem?

Tags: integration, derivatives, trigonometry, differential

I attempting to get an explicit form of a trigonometric function in terms of y and x. this is the problem and solution:

[problem and solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCSsc.png)

i only got to the expression 
$\frac{1}{7}\ \sin(7y)\ = \ 7\cos^2\ (x)$ but I do not know how to express this explicitly, as a function y in terms of x.

thanks

Comment: just apply arcsin and do some algebra to get the given closed form.

Comment: You've accidently duplicated the 7. In your link, the formula is just $$\sin 7y = 7\cos^2 x$$From here the next step is to take the arcsin, just as they did in the solution, then finally divide by 7. What is it about this that you do not understand?  Just note that only $x$ small enough that $\cos^2 x \le 1/7$ are in the domain. For $x$ with a higher value of $\cos^2 x$, there is no number $y$ that will work.